# Determining if a 16 bit binary number is negative or positive

Tags: c++

I'm creating a library for a temperature sensor that has a 16-bit value in binary that is being returned. I'm trying to find the best way to check if that value returned is negative or positive. I'm curious as to whether or not I can check if the most significant bit is a 1 or a 0 and if that would be the best way to go about it, how to successfully implement it.

I know that I can convert it to decimal and check that way but I just was curious if there was an easier way. I've seen it implemented with shifting values but I don't fully understand that method. (I'm super new to c++)

```
float TMP117::readTempC(void)
{
    int16_t digitalTemp;      // Temperature stored in the TMP117 register

    digitalTemp = readRegister(TEMP_RESULT); //Reads the temperature from the sensor

    // Check if the value is a negative number
    /*Insert code to check here*/

    // Returns the digital temperature value multiplied by the resolution
    // Resolution = .0078125
    return digitalTemp*0.0078125; 
}
```

I'm not sure how to check if the code works and I haven't been able to compile it and run it on the device because the new PCB design and sensor has not come in the mail yet.

Comment: The meaning of the value returned by your sensor **totally** depend on the sensor itself. How are we supposed to know what kind of value it returns? Read the sensors' docs, then you'll know,

Comment: Assuming that `digitalTemp` is a 16-bit integer that uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), then yes, you cancheck the most-significant-bit.  But in that case, you also could just directly compare `digitalTemp < 0`.

Comment: The sensor may return temperature in Kelvin in which case the 16 bit value should be treated as unsigned. It's also possible it's returned as Fahrenheit or Centigrade which have negative temps. In that case treat it as a signed, two's compliment number. Check the docs.

Comment: 1 ounce is 0.0078125 gallons. That's a really freakish coincidence...

Comment: Why do you actually need to know whether it is negative?  It makes no difference to the conversion from sensor resolution to Celsius.

Comment: @doug Given the name of the function and the return expression, I would imagine that the sensor units are 0.0078125 of a degree Celsius. I wouldn't over think it, if the existing code is incorrect or misleading, that is a different issue than the subject of this question.

Comment: Why do you actually need to know whether it is negative?  It makes no difference to the conversion from sensor resolution to Celsius.  I would be amazed however if your sensor actually produces a signed value in any case, and would expect an offset to need to be applied: `return (digitalTemp + OFFSET) * RESOLUTION) ;` where `OFFSET` may be negative if the sensor minimum range is negative.

Comment: Apparently the sensor outputs in Celsius scaled by 128 so the 16 bit value would be treated as two's complement. https://www.mouser.com/new/Texas-Instruments/ti-tmp117-temperature-sensor/

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is why test whether the temperature is negative? The function returns a floating point value correctly signed so what is the point of testing it in the function?

Comment: If you are able to correctly do a `return digitalTemp*0.0078125` there is no need to worry about checking the sign with anything other than standard comparisons like `digitalTemp < 0`.     If you need to do the comparison by examining bits, then you probably need to do something funky when multiplying by a `double` literal too.    Either way, you need to check the specification of the device to know what is appropriate.

Comment: @doug Good spot. In which case return digitalTemp / 128.0f;  would be a much clearer implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that I can convert it to decimal and check that way

I am not sure what you mean.  An integer is an integer, it is an arithmetic object you just compare it with zero:

```
if( digitalTemp < 0 )
{
    // negative
}
else
{
    // positive
}
```

You can as you suggest test the MSB, but there is no particular benefit, it lacks clarity, and will break or need modification if the type of `digitalTemp` changes.

```
if( (digitalTemp & 0x8000 )
{
    // negative
}
else
{
    // positive
}
```

"conversion to decimal", can only be interpreted as *conversion to a decimal string representation of an integer*, which does not make your task any simpler, and is entirely unnecessary.

> I'm not sure how to check if the code works and I haven't been able to compile it and run it on the device because the new PCB design and sensor has not come in the mail yet.

Compile and run it on a PC in a test harness with stubs for teh hardware dependent functions.  Frankly if you are new to C++, you are perhaps better off practising the fundamentals in a PC environment with generally better debug facilities and faster development/test iteration in any case.

Comment: C++ does not mandate 2s complement representation of signed integers. Testing the MSB is thus not guaranteed to work, besides being overly convoluted for probably no benefit.

Comment: @IInspectable Since the OP uses `int16_t` C++ mandates that type is two's compliment when the type exists. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer. Agree it's overly convoluted.

Comment: @dou: That's true. I keep forgetting, that C++ imposes different rules for different integer types ([P0907R4](http://wg21.link/P0907R4)). Still, since the OP is asking, how to test whether their `int16_t` is negative (which is trivial), it is quite possible, that what they are looking at simply isn't a two's complement signed integer. Who knows what the hardware really returns (maybe an unsigned value, maybe some fixed-point decimal, or maybe even different encodings depending on the actual configuration).

Comment: @IInspectable It is rather a matter of the nature of the sensor register representation than the compiler or machine representation.  That said, int16_t is required to be two's complement.  Even if that were not the case, portability to some unlikely theoretical implementation is hardly an issue.  The bit test solution is in any case ill-advised as I have pointed out.

Comment: @IInspectable One commenter has suggested the sensor with a link.  It is it seems fixed point with 7 fraction bits. Hence the multiply by 0.0078125 which is in fact a divide by 128.  Even then the test for negative is valid before or after the float conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In general

```
float TMP117::readTempC(void)
{
    int16_t digitalTemp;      // Temperature stored in the TMP117 register

    digitalTemp = readRegister(TEMP_RESULT); //Reads the temperature from the sensor

    // Check if the value is a negative number
    if (digitalTemp < 0)
    {
         printf("Dang it is cold\n");
    }


    // Returns the digital temperature value multiplied by the resolution
    // Resolution = .0078125
    return digitalTemp*0.0078125; 
}
```

Comment: The other guys are correct too.   We are assuming that  readRegister returns an actual int16_t.

Comment: Any other interpretation of _"sensor that has a 16-bit value in binary that is being returned. "_ would seem somewhat far fetched.

Comment: It's his code, and his hardware.   It might be unsigned, or ones complement.   We have no way to know for sure, hence the cavaets.

Comment: The nature of the sensor is irrelevant to the fundamental question of "_Determining if a 16 bit binary number is negative or positive_" and just a distraction.  I'd take it at face value; if  the the code does not then work, then that is a different question.